# how to run screenfetch as a command?

Tags: macos, bash

I have the latest executable screenfetch-dev in /Users/gav/scripts/ folder. I can execute it fine by running `/Users/gav/scripts/screenfetch-dev`

But how do I make it a command, so I can just type `screenfetch` and make it run?

I'm using OS X 10.8 ML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the default shell in OS X (BASH), you can add the following to the `.bash_profile` in your home directory (so `/Users/gav/.bash_profile` - you may have to create this file yourself if you've never used it before):

```
alias screenfetch="/Users/gav/scripts/screenfetch-dev"
```

Alternatively, you could add your `scripts` folder to your `PATH`, by adding the following line to the same `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/Users/gav/scripts:$PATH"
```

The first method (creating an alias) allows you to assign any name as a "shortcut" for anything else - when the command is run, the BASH shell simply substitutes the "shortcut" for the full command. In this case, you could run the script simply by typing `screenfetch`.

The second method (adding the folder to your PATH variable) allows you to use any of the contents of the `scripts` folder from anywhere inside the shell, although you still have to use the script's full name to access it - in this case it would be `screenfetch-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I have in .bash_profile lines:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

And always creating ~/bin folder with custom binaries I can use. And it is automatically added to path if exists. I'm taken this code from ubuntu's .bashrc

after this I can just pass command "screenfetch-dev" or if file is renamed to screenfetch then "screenfetch"

and command to make your "screenfetch-dev" file in "~/bin" executable(if it doesn't set as executable):

```
chmod +x ~/bin/screenfetch-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Move *screenfetch-dev* to `/usr/bin` and then add *screenfetch* or *screenfetch-dev* to .bashrc

***(OR)***

Add `/Users/you/Downloads/screenfetch-dev` to .bashrc